# Store only 'column' data in h5py without loading in the entire data file

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

I have a relatively large dataset (about 8GB),  and read it in to a jupyter notebook using h5py.

The shape of the dataset ends up being something like (50000000, 384). My ideal dataset would have this transposed, so that I can look at each 'column' in the dataset. The only way I have been able to achieve getting each 'column' is by either indexing for each column (which is very slow and CPU intensive because it goes row by row in the 50000000 rows) or convert the h5 data to a np.array and transpose that - which also is very slow and ineffective.

For example, I have an h5 file:

```
chunk_file = h5py.File(chunk_fil_1, "r")

chunk_file["ex_dat"]
```

output:

```
HDF5 dataset "ex_dat": shape (50000000, 384)
```

If I do this:

```
len(chunk_file["ex_dat"][0])
```

output:

```
384
```

This is where I would like my output to be all 50000000 appearances of the '0th' column.

Is there an efficient way to index an h5 file for 'column' like data without reading each row? Or other alternatives for reading this large data set? My end goal is to store individual 'columns' into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: What does `arr = chunk_file["ex_dat"][:,0]` do?  I expect that it reads the 0 column.  It will be slower than reading `chunk_file["ex_dat"][0,:]`, but should still be reasonable.

Comment: Do you want a `Dataframe` with 384 columns, and the 50... rows?  You'll have just have read the whole thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418649/read-part-of-h5-dataset-python/54209593#54209593

Answer (score 0):

So `chunk_file['ex_dat']` is a `numpy` array of shape `(50000000, 384)`. Indexing this with an integer automatically grabs a row, which is the expected behavior. To grab a column instead of a row in a `numpy` array, just index it like

`chunk_file['ex_dat'][:,0]`

where `:` is "all rows" and `0` is the first column. This is the exact same thing as transposing the matrix (`array.T` with `numpy`) and then taking the first row

`chunk_file['ex_dat'].T[0]`

Comment: Right, this also takes up a bunch of my CPU - presumably because it is still reading each row, whereas all I need is the column info. Unless I am interpreting this wrong, and it is actually just a computationally intensive act to look for the 0th index in each row?

Comment: @Pierpressure, the data is laid out on the file in `C` order, row by row.  So yes, loading `[:,0]` means it will have skip forward 384 elements for each read.  But there's no way around that, given how the data is stored.  If as the name suggests the data is `chunked`, then you can read subsets of the rows to save memory.  Check the `h5py` docs.