# read part of h5 dataset python

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-files, h5py

I'm reading in large sets of data from an .h5 file, (200,000 points per dataset) and I currently don't need all of it so what I've been doing is reading in the data, then truncating it after.

Is there a way to only read the first X items of an h5 dataset?

Comment: You can use `numpy` like slicing: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this...

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

filename = 'file.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

key = list(f.keys())[0]

data = list(f[key][1])
```

Indexing may vary for `key` and `f[key]`, where `[0]` is an arbitrary dataset of `file.hdf5` and `[1]` is just an arbitrary column I grabbed.